# Given $\sum_{n=0}^N \alpha_n a_n \geq 0$ if $\sum_{n=0}^N \alpha_n x^n \geq 0$, prove $\mu$ uniquely exists with $a_n = \int_0^1 x^n d\mu$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

This is an exercise in Reed & Simon's book on functional analysis.

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of numbers with the following property: If $\sum_{n=0}^N \alpha_n x^n \geq 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ then $\sum_{n=0}^N \alpha_n a_n \geq 0$. Prove that there is a unique, (positive) measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ with $a_n = \int_0^1 x^n d\mu$.

I've been stuck on this problem. So far my only thought has been to somehow use the Riesz-Markov theorem. Can anyone provide a hint on how to begin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\varphi$ be the linear functional defined on the space of real valued polynomials $\mathcal{P}\subset C_{\mathbb{R}}[0,1]$ by $$ \varphi(p)=\sum a_n\alpha_n,\quad p(x)=\sum \alpha_nx^n$$ By assumption the functional is positive. Moreover if $|p(x)|\le 1$ for $0\le x\le  1$ then $1\pm p(x)\ge 0.$ Hence $\varphi(1)\pm \varphi(p)\ge 0$ which implies $|\varphi(p)|\le \varphi(1).$  Therefore the functional $\varphi $ is bounded on $\mathcal{P}$ with respect to the norm on $ C_{\mathbb{R}}[0,1].$ By the density of the polynomials it extends uniquely to the bounded linear positive functional $\tilde{\varphi}$ on $C_{\mathbb{R}}[0,1]$. Hence there is a unique nonnegative measure $\mu$ such that $$a_n=\varphi(x^n)=\tilde{\varphi}(x^n)=\int\limits_0^1x^n\,d\mu(x)$$

Comment: Thank you! How does the polynomials being dense mean that the linear functional can be uniquely extended?

Comment: Also, why do you consider $|p(x)| < 1$? Is the value 1 arbitrary here?

Comment: The norm of the functional is given by supremum on the unit ball. That's why $\|p\|\le 1$ is used. Concerning the extension: it is a general fact: let $T_0$ be a bounded operator from a normed space $X_0\subset X$ to a Banach space $Y.$ If $X_0$ is a dense subspace of $X,$ the operator extends uniquely to the entire space $X.$

Comment: See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_linear_extension)

Comment: Thank you for all your help!